# Dúvida Reative em MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, html, meteorjs, meteor

Opa, é o seguinte, gostaria de saber como faço para assim que começar a digitar, algo no input, automaticamente atualizar um helper para ser mostrado no template.

eu tentei desse jeito, só que não está mudando em tempo real:

```
Template.hello.onCreated(function(){
    this.name = new ReactiveVar();
})

Template.hello.helpers({
    name: function(){
        return Template.instance().name.get();
    }
})

Template.hello.events({
    'change input' : function(){
        var inputName = document.querySelector('input');
        Template.instance().name.set(inputName.value);
    }
})
```

tentei também com o evento 'focus', mas não funcionou

index.html

```
{{> hello }}
<template name="hello">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <p>Hello {{name}}</p>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

consegui resolver sem usar ReactiveVar, usei Session no lugar.

```
Template.hello.events({
    'input input': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var teste = e.target.value;
        Session.set('name',teste);
    }
});

Template.hello.helpers({
    name: function(){
        return Session.get('name');
    }
})
```